# Change value of custom category attribute in front end

Tags: category

I am installing a custom attribute through the normal Magento module install script. It is a simple select box with Yes or No:

```
<?php

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'my_attribute',
    array(
        'label'            => 'My attribute label',
        'group'            => 'My Group',   //will be created if necessary
        'type'             => 'int',
        'class'            => 'validate-number',
        'source'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'required'         => false,
        'input'            => 'select',
        'global'           => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'          => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

This is all good - it installs fine and if I change the value in the admin area the value gets saved correctly.

I also need a way to manually set that value via AJAX. This controller gets called correctly via a `http://www.mywebsite.com/mymodule/setmyattribute/index/id/1`:

```
<?php

class Mynamespace_Mymodule_SetmyattributeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{        

    public function indexAction() 
    {

        $categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); // Get id from params (1)

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); // Load category (loads fine)
        $category->setMyattribute(0); // <-- set Attribute
        $category->save(); // <-- save the category

        var_dump($category->getMyattribute()); // <-- Equals 0 here which is correct but doesn't equal 0 in the admin area

        /** Re-index the products and category EAV **/
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(5); $process->reindexAll();  // Re-index category EAV
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(6); $process->reindexAll();  // Re-index Category Products

        echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('status'=>'success'));

        die();

    }


}
```

Now the `var_dump` above does as expected and reports `0`. However it doesn't seem to save it properly as in the admin area the value is still `1`. Why is this and how do I make it save correctly?

In my stand-alone Magento scripts when I am setting category attributes I have to put this line at the top:

```
<?php

Mage::app('admin'); // And not ('default')
```

To set custom category attributes, how do I achieve the same with the above controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @TimVroom's answer please use store emulation in favor of changing the `currentStore` or setting the `isSecureArea`. You can read more about emulation on the [Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/).

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_SetmyattributeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{        

    public function indexAction() 
    {

        $categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); // Get id from params (1)

        // start emulation
        $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(0);


        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); // Load category (loads fine)
        $category->setMyattribute(0); // <-- set Attribute
        $category->save(); // <-- save the category


        // stop, return to origional env.
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

        /** Re-index the products and category EAV **/
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(5); $process->reindexAll();  // Re-index category EAV
        $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(6); $process->reindexAll();  // Re-index Category Products

        echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('status'=>'success'));

        exit;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to save categories when in an frontend store.
As seen in an other post you can add this before the category init.

```
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
```

If that doesn't work you can set the store to be admin

```
Mage:app()->setCurrentStore(0);
```

This way it should save. But beware it is a potential security risk.